# Moved offices and now cannot connect remotely to postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

Everything was working in my previous office. I've now moved to a new office, and cannot connect remotely to postgres.  SSH works though. My IP is currently 70.90.155.138.

> Could not connect to server: connection timed out

IP tables config:

```
#  Allpw postgres connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -s 70.90.155.138/16 -j ACCEPT


iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:http-alt:8090
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:60000:61000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  70.90.0.0/16         anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Listen_addresses is set correctly and not commented:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Postgres is running:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql status
Running clusters: 9.1/main
```

and listening:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status
Running clusters: 9.1/main
user1@finance1:/var/log$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17772/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      17772/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5667832  17772/postgres      /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

And I'm not seeing any failed connections in the IPtables log:

```
tail -5000 /var/log/kern.log | grep DPT=5432
```

What have I failed to check here?  What could cause this to stop working when the only thing that has changed is the location of my laptop?

Comment: is there a new firewall in your new location that might be blocking the port, or even the ISP perhaps?  maybe try allowing from anywhere temporarily to see if there's a problem with the ip address you're allowing?

Comment: I agree that it seems likely it's being blocked on my network.  Unfortunately, I don't have access there, so it looks like I'm going to have to see if I can find someone who can help.

Comment: Also, I managed to connect to the database from another box outside my current network, so it looks like I'm being blocked somewhere.

Comment: Try running traceroute using different port numbers to see where the packets are being blocked. For example `traceroute -n -T -p 5432 example.com`